# Why request user is undefined in Sapper App

Tags: node.js, express, svelte, sapper, svelte-3

I cannot set a req.user in my Sapper app, what am I doing wrong

```
express()
    .use(
        bodyParser.urlencoded({
            extended: true
        }),
        bodyParser.json(),
        compression({
            threshold: 0
        }),
        sirv('static', {
            dev
        }),
        cookieParser(),
        session({
            store: store,
            secret: 'somesecret',
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: true,
            cookie: {
                secure: true,
                maxAge: 604800000,
            }
        }),
        passport.initialize(),
        passport.session(),
        sapper.middleware({
            session: (req, res) => {
                let user = req.session.user
                return {
                    user
                }
            }
        }),


    )
```

i have a login component from which im using fetching

in login folder i have a `login.js` file a server side route  and i cannot get my `req.user` not `req.session.user` , not `req.session.passport`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I installed the module "express-session". (This module works with polka.js too)

And set the sapper's middleware:

```
sapper.middleware({
   session: (req, res) => ({
      user: req.session.user
   })
```

I wrote a 'api/login/' to the sever side and a login page.
Once the server recognize the user with his login and pass', I use a goto(".").

**The goto()'s behavior should be like a location.href. But this is not.
So I replace goto(".") by location.href(".").** With this, I have the session's data from the server.(in the preload and with the stores => $session.user).

I hope that can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found partial solution, please correct this if Iam wrong. So entire app is controlled over sapper.middleware and server it self has no automatic effect on it. 
So no req.user is set, no session and no cookie value is set, every thing must be manually set from authentication route.

So my solution was to set cookie in login post route, so in login.js file.

```
import passport from 'passport'

export async function post(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.json(err)
        }
        if (user) {
            // console.log(req)
            return res.status(201).cookie('user', req.sessionID).json({
                email: user.email,
                id: user._id
            })
        }
        if (info) {
            return res.json(info)
        }
    })(req, res, next);


}
```

in login.svelte component i set my session (SAPPER MIDDLEWARE SESSION)

```
session.set({ user: true, email: user_data.email, id: user_data.id });
```

So my Further action is to check if sessionid exist in session store on server if yes continue if no  set user to null and redirect  to login.

is it correct ? Is it safe enough ?

**Edit**

So My partial "solution" is not right for any one having the same problem with passport authentication solution is

1. you must define route in server.js prior sapper.middleware
2. app.httpRequest('/route',YOURAUTHENTICATION MIDDLEWARE)
3. in your route.js file or in route folder index.js file you will have your req.user
4. in sapper middleware your session object must look like this

```
     session: (req, res) => ({
                        user: req.session.passport ? req.session.passport.user : null })
```

if you will try to pass req.user it will not be serialized by sapper / devalue package and you will keep getting error.

After this in your route.js you can preload user from session. hope this was clear !